# How to only show selected dimensions via Tableau JS

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I'm developing an interactive report via Tableau JS. I need to restrict user to see only some dimensions based on user's permission. Tableau Js has filter capability but it is just to 'select' dimensions, thus user still can see other dimensions.

Here is code we have tried to use for the restriction, applyFilterAsync(). But didn't work as expected.

```
activeSheet.applyFilterAsync(
   "Dimension",
   ["Value 1", "Value 2"],
   tableau.FilterUpdateType.REPLACE
);
```

[It shown Value 3 and 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBrgn.png)

[But I expected only Value 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCmcf.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this with workaround. I duplicated the dimension I wanted to filter and named it something else. Select 'Only Relevant Values' in The original dimension. So when the values in the copy dimension changes, this will change the value in the original dimension. Here we can control any value in the original dimension by changing the value in the copy dimension via a filter api. The last step is to hide the copy dimension from user eyes. That works for me.